# How to deploy continuously using just One EC2 instance with ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, continuous-integration, travis-ci, amazon-ecs

I want to deploy my nodejs webapp continuously using just **One EC2 instance** with ECS. I cannot create multiple instances for this app.

My current continuous integration process: 
Travis build the code from github, build tag and push docker image and deployed to ECS via [ECS Deploy shell script](https://github.com/silinternational/ecs-deploy).

Everytime the deployment happen, following error occurs. Because the port 80 is always used by my webapp.

```
The closest matching container-instance ffa4ec4ccae9
is already using a port required by your task
```

1. Is it actually possible to use ECS with one instance? (documentation not clear)
2. How to get rid of this port issue on ECS? (stop the running container)
3. What is the way to get this done without using a Load Balancer?
4. Anything I missed or doing apart from the best practises?

Comment: If you have an application that cannot tolerate being offline while it is being deployed you should consider your choice of only having 1 EC2 instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is the **port conflict**, which occurs when deploying a second instance of the task on the same node in the cluster. Nothing should stop you from having multiple container instances apart from that (e.g. when not using a load balancer; binding to any ports at all).

To solve this issue, Amazon [introduced](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/powerful-aws-platform-features-now-for-containers/) a **dynamic ports** feature in a recent update:

> Dynamic ports makes it easier to start tasks in your cluster without having to worry about port conflicts. Previously, to use Elastic Load Balancing to route traffic to your applications, you had to define a fixed host port in the ECS task. This added operational complexity, as you had to track the ports each application used, and it reduced cluster efficiency, as only one task could be placed per instance. Now, you can specify a dynamic port in the ECS task definition, which gives the container an unused port when it is scheduled on the EC2 instance. The ECS scheduler automatically adds the task to the application load balancer’s target group using this port. To get started, you can create an application load balancer from the EC2 Console or using the AWS Command Line Interface (CLI). Create a task definition in the ECS console with a container that sets the host port to 0. This container automatically receives a port in the ephemeral port range when it is scheduled.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it using the green/blue deployment pattern:

1. Host your containers on port 8080 & 8081 (or whatever port you want). Let's call 8080 green and 8081 blue. (You may have to switch the networking mode from bridge to host to get this to work on a single instance).
2. Use Elastic Load Balancing to redirect the traffic from 80/443 to green or blue.
3. When you deploy, use a script to swap the active listener on the ELB to the other color/container.

This also allows you to roll back to a 'last known good' state.

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-load-balancing.html for more information.

Comment: With a single instance you *might* be able to do it without an ELB if you switch the networking to host and expose two ports, and maybe use nginx or something on the ECS host to redirect the traffic. However, using a load balancer gives you so many other benefits I would strongly recommend using one.